# Column 'order_date' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I want to make customer retention cohort. I have columns customerId and order_date. I am using self joins but its showing some errors.

Self-joins

```
SELECT 
   p1.customerId AS id,
   MONTH(order_date) as month,
   YEAR(order_date) as year 
FROM
    jugnoo AS p1
        LEFT JOIN
    jugnoo AS p2 ON p1.id = p2.id
WHERE
    p2.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                 (customerId) AS id
              FROM
                  jugnoo
              WHERE
                    MONTH(order_date) = 06
                AND YEAR(order_date) = 2017
              order by year(order_date), month(order_date))
order by 3, 2;
```

Expected customerId's that matches the condition but its showing an error message "Column 'order_date' in field list is ambiguous   0.00072 sec"

Comment: change order_date to p1.order_date. SELECT 
   p1.customerId AS id,
   MONTH(p1.order_date) as month,
   YEAR(p1.order_date) as year

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function**, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. simply write `(SELECT DISTINCT customerId as AS id ...`.

Comment: When you did your Self Join and duplicated the table you now have to declare which `order_date` you're using in your `Select` either `p1.` or `p2.`

Comment: The LEFT JOIN above returns regular INNER JOIN. Move the p2 condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: No JOIN needed. Simply do `WHERE p1.id  IN ...`.

Comment: **Pro tip**: When doing self-joins or other complex queries, get in the habit of always qualifying column names. For example, `p1.order_date` rather than `order_date`. It will save you this kind of hassle, and the next person to look at your query will thank you because your intent is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the order_date. It's an ambiguous column: that means that you can find this column more than one table.
Just specificy from which table you need this column. In this case it appears to be p1, so you would use p1.order_date

Answer (score 0):

In the output columns section you are referring to columns 'order_date' that exist in both joined tables (its a self join but the SQL engine is not able to "guess" to which of them you are referring to).

In the output section, prefix "p1." or "p2." to the order_name, depending on which of the join parts you want to output the information from.

I assume that it would be p1 but....

Answer (score 0):

No `JOIN` needed. Simply use the p1.id column instead.

```
SELECT 
   p1.customerId AS id,
   MONTH(p1.order_date) as month,
   YEAR(p1.order_date) as year 
FROM
    jugnoo AS p1
WHERE
    p1.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                  customerId AS id
              FROM
                  jugnoo p2
              WHERE
                    MONTH(p2.order_date) = 06
                AND YEAR(p2.order_date) = 2017
              order by year(p2.order_date), month(p2.order_date))
order by 3, 2;
```

When several tables are involved, it's good programming practice to qualify all columns. Like `p1.id` instead of just `id`. Less error prone, easier to read and maintain.

**Edit: (As requested)**

Use a *correlated subquery* to get data for each month:

```
SELECT 
   p1.customerId AS id,
   MONTH(p1.order_date) as month,
   YEAR(p1.order_date) as year 
FROM
    jugnoo AS p1
WHERE
    p1.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                  p2.customerId AS id
              FROM
                  jugnoo p2
              WHERE
                   MONTH(p2.order_date) = MONTH(p1.order_date) 
                AND YEAR(p2.order_date) = YEAR(p1.order_date))
order by 3, 2;
```

Comment: this query will work for month 06 and year 2017 but i have to make it work for all months (like my next month and year will be 07 and 2017) and i have to do same thing for next month and year also, can you help me with how can i write a single query and make it work with all months and year present in order_date column.

Comment: Stay tuned, I'll be back.

Comment: Hey thanks for help!! I was looking for some different output. I am attaching a link to photo, that might make you more clear what i am looking for: [link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3-4ZXfqUjmtOHhnMFNKV2hMOGNKM0YyZTdlang0ZGVINHk0

Answer (score 0):

Use alias before column name for example

```
p1.order_date
```

OR

```
p2.order_date
```

whenever and wherever you want to use that column you need to specify table; 
so use table name or just use table alias like above.